# How do you generate a Ed25519Keypair that uses a Mnemonic Phrase using SolanaWeb3 API?

Tags: web3.js

How do you generate a Ed25519Keypair that uses a Mnemonic Phrase using JavaScript SolanaWeb3 API? I'd like to be able to generate a wallet that I can also use with browser extension wallet apps like Phantom Wallet which only accept a Mnemonic Phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet to generate Ed25519 Keypair form [rust official docs](https://docs.rs/solana-ed25519-dalek/0.2.0/solana_ed25519_dalek/struct.Keypair.html):

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate ed25519_dalek;

use rand::Rng;
use rand::rngs::OsRng;
use ed25519_dalek::Keypair;
use ed25519_dalek::Signature;

let mut csprng: OsRng = OsRng::new().unwrap();
let keypair: Keypair = Keypair::generate(&mut csprng);
```

Comment: How do you do it using JavaScript SolanaWeb3 API?

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it in JavaScript:

```
//npm install bip39 ed25519-hd-key @solana/web3.js
let util = require('util');
let bip39 = require('bip39');
let ed25519_hd_key = require('ed25519-hd-key');
let solana_web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");

function full_inspect_obj(obj) {
    return util.inspect(obj, {
        showHidden: true,
        depth: null,
        colors: false,
        maxArrayLength: null
    });
}

function generate_wallet() {
    let wallet = {};
    let mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
    let master_seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
    let index = 0;
    let derived_path = "m/44'/501'/" + index +"'/0'";
    let derived_seed = ed25519_hd_key.derivePath(derived_path, master_seed.toString('hex')).key;
    wallet.keypair = solana_web3.Keypair.fromSeed(derived_seed);
    wallet.mnemonic = mnemonic;
    wallet.publicAddress = wallet.keypair.publicKey.toBase58();
    return wallet;
}

let wallet = generate_wallet();
console.log(full_inspect_obj(wallet));
```